# Trying to find prime numbers

Tags: c

I'm a first year student in a programming university and my first assignment is to find the sum of prime numbers between 3990000000 and 4010000000. The problem is everything I do, when I run the program it says the sum is 0 with a return value of 25. I've been trying to debug this code but with no luck, could someone help me?

My code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define STARTNUMBER 3990000000 
#define ENDNUMBER 4010000000

int main() {
  unsigned int num;
  int j, c, flag, sum = 0;
  flag = 1;
  c = 5;
  j = 7;
  for (num = STARTNUMBER; num <= ENDNUMBER; num++) {
    if (num % 2 == 0) { /*if number mod 2 equals zero go to next number*/
      flag = 0;
      break;
    }
    if (num % 3 == 0) { /*if number mod 3 equals zero go to next number*/
      flag = 0;
      break;
    } else
      /*check if number is prime with the sequences 5+6+6...<=sqrt(number) and 7+6+6..<=sqrt(number)*/
      while (c * c <= num && j * j <= num && flag == 1) { 
        if (num % c == 0 || num % j == 0) {
          flag = 0;
          break;
        }
        c += 6;
        j += 6;
      }
    if (flag == 1)
      sum++;
  }
  printf("There are %d prime numbers", sum);
}
```

Comment: You `break` out of the loop in your first iteration.

Comment: Are you looking for the sum of the prime numbers (as you've stated), or just for the number of prime numbers (as you've done in the code)?

Comment: Like @tkausl already said, you need to revisit the topic of for loops and how the `break` instruction works exactly

Comment: As for the "return value of 25", it is the number of characters printed by `printf` (which is missing a newline at the end, BTW), since your `main` is missing a `return` statement of its own.

Comment: Once you have fixed your `break`ing logic, you will see that you must reset the values of `flag`, `c` and `j` for each new `num`. At the moment, you just set these values once at the beginning.

Comment: `break` -> `continue`; `sum++` -> `sum += num`; to avoid overflow, `unsigned int num` -> `#include <stdint.h>`...`uint_64 num`; I think `flag = 1` should be inside the loop, but you actually don't need `flag`.

Answer (score 0):

You are asking for the sum of the prime number, even if your code is just printing how many they are. Assuming you've misunderstood the exercise, I try to show a possible problem of your original question, glimpsing a possible trick in your exercise since the interval is very close to 2<sup>32</sup>.

Assuming also you are on a 64-bit environment, if there are at least two prime numbers in that inteval, the sum is going to be greater than `INT_MAX` (2<sup>31</sup> - 1). An `int` is not sufficient to store a value, and also `unsigned int` is not sufficient since `UINT_MAX` is 2<sup>32</sup> - 1.

Finally, assuming you've solved your problems with the `break` statements already described in the comments, try to store your `sum` variable into a `unsigned long int`, and replace the last part of the loop with

```
if (flag==1)
    sum += num;
```

Comment: Yeah my mistake, by saying the sum of numbers, I meant how many numbers are between the startnumber and endnumber, thus storing the sum variable into unsigned int is enough. As for the use of the break command, doesn't the loop stop and continues to the next number if the command where break is in (in this case those if commands) is false? (flag=0). I've tried removing the break commands and leaving it with the flag command, but it didn't help.

Comment: You should call that a "count" not a "sum". Variable names are important--you and other humans may have to read the code years later, and might reasonably (and mistakenly) assume that "sum" is a sum.